# How can I get more than one Stackdriver notifications from a given metric?

Tags: google-app-engine, stackdriver

I defined alerts based on a log metric. (For testing, I made sure that this is a metric that occurs every minute.)

I get an email, as follows -- but only one. How can I have further emails sent when the metric is triggered again? Note that after I got that one email, I logged in and "Acknowledged" the incident but no more emails come.

```
From: Stackdriver Alerts <alerts@stackdriver.com>
Date: Tue, Feb 21, 2017 at 5:35 PM
Subject: [ALERT] Suggested Condition on myapp   default:20161017t181616 
To: a..@...s.com


Stackdriver has detected that one of your resources has entered an alert state. 
Summary: logging/user/FilterMetricIContainerOnUrlAndRequestStatus for myapp  default:20161017t181616 with metric labels {log=appengine.googleapis.com/request_log} is below the threshold of 100 with a value of 0.016666666666666666. 
Violation Began: 2017-02-21 15:28:48 UTC (6 mins 59 secs) 
Condition Name: Suggested Condition 

View violation details: https://app.google.stackdriver.com/account/login/cloud-eng-dev/incidents/0.k99rt8xwbh5i
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be receiving a notification for every incident that's open. I suggest if this isn't the case and you've verified that the conditions are met again (so the metric is in violation again), that you click on the bottom right "Send Feedback" button, and include my name so I catch it. That will help provide more info into your situation.
Thanks for using Stackdriver!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're getting one incident that doesn't close, which suggests that your alerting policy is defined too loosely. Is your alerting duration shorter than the interval between log messages? I'd suggest making it no more than half the interval.

Aaron Sher, Stackdriver engineer